# Automatically answer a window.confirm using VBA

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I have some VBA code that opens a webpage, then calls a javascript function that deletes a file off of the page. When this function is called, it calls a window.confirm in the HTML to make sure that the user really wants to delete the file. The options are yes and cancel. My question- Is there any way to automatically make my VBA code answer yes? As it is, I can automate everything but the "yes" click, which means I still have to sit there and click yes for every file that it wants to delete; it'd be nice to run the code and be able to walk away.
edit: if it helps, here is the code I'm using to execute the javascipt. Also, the javascript function code

My code:

```
Dim CurrentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy: Set CurrentWindow = IE.Document.parentWindow

m = 2

Do Until date_var < "2011-7-1"

        Cells(1, 11).Value = Range("j1") - m
        date_var = Cells(1, 11).Value
        date_var = Format(date_var, "yyyy-m-d")

        Call CurrentWindow.execScript("Delete('filepath_here_" & date_var & ".csv?DELETE')")
```

Javascript Function:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function Delete(What)
{
   if (window.confirm("Do you really want to delete this file"))
   {
      location.href = What;
   }
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: If you own the web page then simply replace the window.confirm call with the literal true.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own the page; I am totally unable to change the actual HTML.

Comment: You could try @minitech's approach. However, I suggest you think of some other solution. What exactly is your problem. Please elaborate more.

Comment: I'm not sure I know how elaborate more; I want to make my VBA code automatically answer yes to a window.confirm pop up. Is there anything else in particular you need to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know VBA, but try the following script:

```
Call CurrentWindow.execScript("location.href='filepath_here_" & date_var & ".csv?DELETE';")
```

That should do the trick. It's better than calling the delete function directly. No function call overhead, no side effects, and no confirm box. Replace the last line of your code with this one and check.

Comment: Hey! What do you know! Thanks Aaadit! I'll make sure to mark this as answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try executing this piece of code when the page loads:

```javascript
window.confirm = function() {
    return true;
};
```

Comment: Not a good idea. It could cause bad side effects. In addition, how would you programmatically inject the script into the page? Browsers are pretty uptight about XSS. You are better off simply replacing the function call with the literal true if you own the page. Otherwise think of a workaround. There must be a more elegant solution to your problem. Expand your question.

Comment: @AaditMShah: If the VBA script can call a JavaScript function, that usually (if not always) means that it's through some kind of WebBrowser control. This means they have total control over the script. What's more, from the sounds of it, the only thing that's happening is deletion so it wouldn't cause side-effects. If it did, then there are alternatives. As for replacing it with the literal `true`, how do you suggest that be done? It would work, but it would definitely be a lot less elegant and harder to understand. (Also, please note that I'm not the OP and the OP is not notified  of comments

Comment: I don't know VBA, so I can't comment on that. Sounds like a game boy advance emulator to me. Anyway, even if you do inject the script if there are any other window.confirm calls on the page, they will all return true. Hence it would cause undesired side-effects. How do you propose to solve that problem?

Comment: @minitech, thanks for the help. Looking at the code that I posted, is there any way you could help me figure out where to place it and how to call it? I tried the "call CurrentWindow.execScript("etc. etc.") with your code and it did NOT like that.

Comment: @Quintis555: Remove the newlines, it should work. But it seems you've found your solution anyway.

Comment: @AaditMShah: I was working under the assumption that there weren't any. The question didn't have that information. Read my previous comment again. And I have *no idea* what you mean by Game Boy Advance emulator.